# Get array from class values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get back an array selecting the class value but I only get the last value.

So this:

```
<input class="test" value="Example 1" />
<input class="test" value="Example 2" />
console.log($(".test").val());
```

Returns me this

```
Example 1
```

How can I get all values of the class? I want to save it in a variable so I can send it with AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method like:

```
var data = $(".test").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();   // ["Example 1", "Example 2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because there are many elements that satisfy the selector ".test", so $(".test") returns an array with all instances that have the class "test", so you should probably loop through the array it returns, like this;

```
$(".test").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = [];
$(".test").each(function(){
   values.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(values);
```

Comment: didn't see your answer when i wrote mine... relax.
+ you didn't fully answer his question, he wanted an array of the values.

Comment: no problem. . .but I don't see the word array anywhere in his question

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `$('.test')` already returns an array with all elements in the DOM that have the class `test`.

So if you need all their values, just iterate over the returned array storing the values into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = $(".test");
```

this will return the array of elements and then you can process the array to get all values.

```
  var x = $(".test");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                alert(x[i].value);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `$(".test")` already returns an array; the array of elements that have class "test". So one option would be to map that array to an array of values. E.g.

```
var valueArray = $.map($(".test"), function(input, indx) {
    return input.value;
});
for (var i = 0, v; v = valueArray[i]; ++i) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

You could also iterate with `each()` and create your own array

Comment: Ah, I'm too slow typing :) others already suggested the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myArray = $('.test').map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

You will get the variable myArray as an array of input values, check this out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/CG8kj/